# Export Environment variables using Python instead of Command Line in Linux

Tags: python, export, environment

I have 2 environments which I need to export before my script can run. If I do not export these, my script will provide an error stating a file/directory is not found.

If I manually export these on the command line, it works fine, but I'm trying to do this in my python script so I won't need to manually export it before running the script.

I've tried googling up with similar issues and found use of os.system() or os.environ(). However neither seem to work for me.

```
   os.system('export TIBCO_NATIVE_INTERFACE_PATH=/opt/gma/venues/nam/arcx_fix_1/libext/libtibems64.so')
   os.system('export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/gma/venues/nam/arcx_fix_1/libext')

OR
   os.environ["TIBCO_NATIVE_INTERFACE_PATH"] = "/opt/gma/venues/nam/arcx_fix_1/libext/libtibems64.so"
   os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/gma/venues/nam/arcx_fix_1/libext"
```

Using either of the above methods do not solve my issue as I still am prompted with a invalid error stating a file/directory is no found.

Comment: Why not save them in `.bash_profile` or something?

Comment: Doesn't work for *LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH*. I'd suggest creating a small shell script that sets them and then invokes your *Python* script.

Comment: Neither one will affect the environment from which the Python script is *called*. The first will only change the environment of a subprocess that immediately exits; the second will change the environment of the script itself.